# Javascript Regular Expression that diallows special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have the below 3 function.
 I cant seem to get the right regular expression
Please assist me

```
    //Allow Alphanumeric,dot,dash,underscore but prevent special character and space
    function Usernames(txtName) {
        if (txtName.value != '' && txtName.value.match(/^[0-9a-zA-Z.-_]+$/) == null) {
            txtName.value = txtName.value.replace(/[\W- ]/g, '');
        }
    }
    //Allow Alphanumeric,dot,dash,underscore and space but prevent special characters
    function Fullnames(txtName) {
        if (txtName.value != '' && txtName.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9. -_]+$/) == null) {
            txtName.value = txtName.value.replace(/[\W-]/g, '');
        }
    }
    //Allow Alphanumeric,dot,dash,underscore the "@" sign but prevent special character and space
    function Email(txtName) {
        if (txtName.value != '' && txtName.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.-_@]+$/) == null) {
            txtName.value = txtName.value.replace(/[\W-]/g, '');
        }
    }
```

Comment: On which you have an issue? In all of them ?

Comment: What exactly is a "Special character"? e.g. Why is `@` not a special character but `&` is?

Comment: `[^a-zA-Z0-9\@\s\.\_\-]` matches anything except for a-z, A-Z, 0-9, @, 
  (white space), . (dot), _ and -, is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

You don't write regular expressions to "prevent" something; they're not blacklists but whitelists. So, if someone is sending in a character that you don't want it's because your regex allowed them to. My guess as to your specific problem has to do with the `.-_` part. In regex's, the `X-Y` means "everything from X to Y" so this would translate to "everything from . (ASCII 2E) to _ (ASCII 5F)" which ironically includes all uppercase and lowercase letters, the numbers 0 to 9, the `/`, the `:`, the `;` and the `@` just to name a few. To avoid this, you should probably change this part to be: `.\-_` as the slash will escape the dash. However, that'll still let your users make names like `.Bob` or `-Larry` and you probably don't want this so your regex should probably read:

```
/^[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z.\-_]*$/
```

This will require the first character to be alphanumeric and any of the remainder to be alphanumeric, the `.`, the `-` or the `_`.

You'll also want to check that your value matches this reg-ex instead of not. I'm not sure what that entails in Javascript but my guess is that it's probably not `value == null`